# HTML5 progress tag not displaying completion state

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I have a simple HTML5 `<progress>` tag:

```
<progress max="100" value="80"></progress>
```

The bar displays but it is all gray, with no completion status (i.e., 80% of the bar is not blue).

When I go to any other page which talks about how to use the `<progress>` tag the completion status shows up perfectly fine.  Just when I stick it in my page, it fails to render properly.

I'm using **AngularJS** and **Bootstrap**.  I'm unsure if that is perhaps causing some trouble?

Why would my `<progress>` tag fail to render the progress correctly?

**UPDATE (additional code)**

Due to using **AngularJS** the surrounding code is more complex then normal, but here we go...

The **AngularJS** root file is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Style Includes -->
</head>

<body ng-App="myApp">

<!-- AngularUI-Router View -->
<ui-view></ui-view>

<!-- JavaScript Includes -->

</body>
</html>
```

My [AngularUI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) loads the following view into the `ui-view` tag for the offending page:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 well well-sm">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <a ui-sref="admin.groups.create" class="list-group-item" ng-class="{ active: isTab('admin.groups.create') }">Create Group Visit <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span></a>
        <a ui-sref="admin.groups.list" class="list-group-item" ng-class="{ active: isTab('admin.groups.list') }">List All Group Visits <span class="badge">[[ allGroups.length ]]</span></a>
      </ul>
      <h4>Upcoming Group Visits</h4>
      <ul class="list-group">
      </ul>
      <h4>Recent Group Visits</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Finally a 3rd view is put into the `ui-view` of the above code block, which displays the `progress` bar.

```
<p>Create the group!!</p>

<progress max="100" value="80"></progress>
```

So, I do have `<!doctype html>` but there are several layers of **AngularUI-Router** views leading down to the progress bar.  Seems they are breaking it somehow, but am not sure if there is something that would convince it to work in this situation.

Comment: Could you show more code, or perhaps a link to a stripped down page that reproduces the problem? Also check to see if you have the correct doctype in your HTML (you'll probably want the HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: as @jingtao said, make sure that your page has `<!DOCTYPE html>` in it.

Comment: Additional code and explanation added.

Comment: Presumably you've checked your dev tools to see if Bootstrap or any other styles or classes are interfering with the progress tag?

Comment: if you make a HTML file with _only_ this progressbar in it, does it look the same?